# I want to query a set of data (multiple rows and columns) and return the rows of data based on an input value (search box) - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-query

Raw data I want to query:

[image: Raw Asset Data]

I want to query this data based on an input value that could feature in any of the columns of data to then return the correct rows of data:

For example if I type in 'A001' as the ID the result will return that row of data with headings, the same as if I typed in 'Desk 1' into my search box:

[image: search box]

The challenge I am having is that I can query only against a single column of data rather than across all - help is much appreciated!

```
=query('RAW ASSET DATA'!A1:D,"SELECT * WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE LOWER(""%"&B2&"%"")",1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=query($A$1:$D$10,"select * where Lower(A) contains '"&H2&"' or A contains '"&H2&"'",1)`

---

There are two `WHERE` conditions joined by **OR**. So either one or the other will apply.

**#1**: `Lower(A) contains '"&H2&"'` - compares the Lowercase value of Column A (the ID). So if the value of H2 is "a", then this condition will be executed

**#2**: `A contains '"&H2&"'` - compares the actual (Uppercase) value of Column A (the ID). So if the value of H2 is "A", then this condition will be executed.

Comment: Thanks @Tedinoz - exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Pleasure. You might consider “accepting” this answer.